# AttributeError: partially initialized module 'random' has no attribute 'randrange' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, random

```
import random

print(random.randrange(1, 10))
```

when i tried this in vs code I am getting an error

Comment: tell and show what error occurs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You've put this code into a file called `random.py` haven't you!  You need to be careful in Python that your module names aren't the same as other things.

For others, I can replicate this by doing:

```bash
cat > random.py << EOF
import random
print(random.randrange(1, 10))
EOF
python random.py
```

results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/smason/random.py", line 1, in <module>
    import random
  File "/home/smason/random.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(random.randrange(1, 10))
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'random' has no attribute 'randrange' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a file called `random.py` outside of your code.

`random` is a python library, so please do not use it to name your files.

Modify the name of that file or delete it and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of your file from random.py to another name that doesn't take a module name such as randm.py this worked for me. Thanks have fun coding.

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers.